# Regular expression for grep to detect sdaa but not sda

Tags: regex, linux, grep

i want to grep for all devices in my linux system except /dev/sda.

My devices f.e.

```
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdb    /dev/sdc  /dev/sde  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdi  /dev/sdk
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdaa  /dev/sdbb   /dev/sdd  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdh  /dev/sdj  /dev/sdl
```

At the moment i'm using following command:

```
ls /dev/sd* | grep '\/dev\/sd[b-z]'
```

which does not detect /dev/sdaa.

I thought i could use a regular expression like this: http://regexr.com/39u99
and invert the result of grep with -v but i couldn't get it to work either.

I would appreciate any help :)

EDIT:

OK many thanks to all of you :) great answers so far.
I would like to extend my question for the case when i also want to exclude /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 etc.

Meaning all but /dev/sda and /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2 /dev/sda3 etc.

Comment: What if you do `grep -v "/dev/sda$"`? This way, exactly `sda` is grepped out.

Comment: Instead of editing your question adding more requirements, do give feedback to the answerers and accept the one that helped you the most. Then, you can ask a new question if needed.

Comment: @random did you want to match `sdaa`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, below regex will help you.

```
\/dev\/sd(a{2}|[b-z]+)
```

```
$ grep -Po '\/dev\/sd(a{2}|[b-z]+)' file.txt 
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdc
/dev/sde
/dev/sdg
/dev/sdi
/dev/sdk
/dev/sdaa
/dev/sdbb
/dev/sdd
/dev/sdf
/dev/sdh
/dev/sdj
/dev/sdl
```

And here is the [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/kE3vX7/1)

instead of regex you can also try bash negation feature to do this.

```
$ ls  !(sda[0-9])
sdaa  sdb  sdbb  sdc  sdd  sde  sdf  sdg  sdh  sdi  sdj  sdk  sdl
```

The negation will be more effective for simple filtering.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`extglob`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) you can avoid `grep` and also any use of regex:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls /dev/sd*!(a)
```

**This will list every file except `/dev/sda`.**

Comment: Great answer! You made it. Feel free to revoke my edit if you don't find it useful, of course :)

Answer (score 1):

Use word boundary like below,

```
ls /dev/sd* | grep -v '/dev/sda\>'
```

It prints all the devices names like `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2`, `/dev/sdb` except `/dev/sda` . `\>` acts as a word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character.

Example:

```
$ ls /dev/sd*
/dev/sda   /dev/sda10  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda5  /dev/sda7  /dev/sda9
/dev/sda1  /dev/sda11  /dev/sda3  /dev/sda6  /dev/sda8  /dev/sdb
$ ls /dev/sd* | grep -v '/dev/sda\>'
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda10
/dev/sda11
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda3
/dev/sda5
/dev/sda6
/dev/sda7
/dev/sda8
/dev/sda9
/dev/sdb
```

If you really wanna regex solution then you could simply use the below,

```
grep -Po '/dev/sd(?!a\b)\S+'
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kE3vX7/2)

**Update:**

> I would like to extend my question for the case when i also want to exclude /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 etc.

That is, he don't want to match `/dev/sda` family.

```
grep -oP '\/dev\/sd(?!a\S*)\S+'
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kE3vX7/3)

Comment: I had never noticed `grep -v` makes the single-line output become multiline.

Comment: yep, me also. But if i copy the text to a file, it prints the whole second line. But when i pipe the output of ls to grep , it displays the output like above. weired.

Comment: @fedorqui: It is not `grep -v` it is `ls` command when used in pipe. Even `ls /dev/sd* | cat` will be multiline output.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers!

I'm using

```
ls /dev/sd* | grep -Po '\/dev\/sd(a{2}|[b-z]+)'
```

which fits my needs the best! :)